# How to substring to get "sts":1" get value 1

Tags: java

```
{"66":{"waktu":"2013-10-01 12:45:11","hp":"+6285716157476","sms":"BKPM:\ntest ke budi","flash":"0","sts":"1"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is appearing the JSON structure... use the JSON parser to parse it

Refer the link [how-to-parse-json-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use Json parser for your String.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String jsonString  = "{" + 
            "   \"66\": {" + 
            "       \"waktu\": \"2013-10-01 12:45:11\"," + 
            "       \"hp\": \"+6285716157476\"," + 
            "       \"sms\": \"BKPM:\\ntest ke budi\"," + 
            "       \"flash\": \"0\"," + 
            "       \"sts\": \"1\"" + 
            "   }" + 
            "}";


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject a = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("66");
    String sts = (String) a.get("sts");



    System.out.println("sts=" + sts);       
}
```

Output:

```
sts=1
```

Comment: why down-vote, please read answer first